# Given program for EV3 Race Car doesn't work, but why?

Tags: ev3, mindstorms, software, steering

I have successfully built an EV3 Race Car with instructions from a fan-made book made by Laurens Valk. In the book, he tells how to make **my blocks** for the rack-and-pinion steering and how to make a remote-control program with those custom blocks, too. I am eager to try it out, but unfortunately one of the my blocks that are required does simply nothing. To be more specific, it does **100%** nothing. In fact, it doesn't even show that screen you see when you run the program.

This is the *center* **my block**, and according to the book it's supposed to check to see if the front wheels are not perfectly straight like the rear wheels (which aren't even supposed to turn, anyway) and if so it will realign them so that they *are* aligned and it should lock them in place. Here is the given blueprint from the book:

[image: resetmyblock]

The author is no longer active on the website where you can contact him, and yes, I *did* update the EV3's firmware and reinstalled the software.

I don't see any reason for the program to not work, so I'm hoping one of you will help to fix it.

Oh, and you'll probably want to know about the other necessary details so here's the part of the book that involves this car:  https://magbuhatrobotics.files.wordpress.com/2017/05/chapter-12.pdf

Comment: You have shown us what the code SHOULD look like, but not what you have actually coded yourself. Can you provide this?

Comment: It should be in the PDF file that I have already given. Pages 25 & 26 should have it, and page 26 should have the blueprint for the center my block. FYI, the reason it says on his program that all the ports are in A and yet for mine it's D is because I stuck my medium motor into Port D instead of A to avoid cramping up physical space and to avoid the visibility of the ports sticking out all over the place.

Comment: Code seems entirely correct to me. Just checking, but you do realize the code is supposed to do nothing if the wheels are aligned ? Do the other myblocks work ?

Comment: The other my blocks work, and I turned the wheels yet the script STILL doesn't do anything.

Comment: Is your D motor fully plugged in? Can you share pictures of the build, and of the entire program you have written?

Comment: Recently I rebuilt the car. I remembered my old question here and just decided to download the files from his site directly. I probably made a mistake somewhere, but now I don't know and I don't care.